# mapping multiple locations in nginx for proxying

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to map a couple of locations in my reverse proxy to a single location on the webserver.  My configuration looks something like this...

```
location ~ ^/(static|images)/(.*)$ { 
  proxy_pass http://server:8080/static/$2;
}
```

This configuration works.

I tried to use `rewrite` along with proxy pass.

`location ~ ^/(static|images)/(.*)$ { 
  rewrite ^/(static|images)/(.*$) /static/$2;
  proxy_pass http://server:8080;
}`

I get the following error now.
`rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing <assetname>`

Since the rewrite rule has one of the locations in my regex, I changed the web server location to `k-static`.  Now I see that nginx is looking for the file in my local folder (`open() "/var/www/html/k-static/assents/p388.img" failed (2: No such file or directory)` instead of forwarding the request to webserver.

My objective is to forward any requests coming with `/static/` or `/images/` to `http://server:8080/static`.  This can be achieved by having two location blocks or the first configuratino.  I'm trying to avoid duplicate location blocks in my nginx configuration.   I really appreciate some help to do it with a rewrite rule. Why is checking the local folder instead of forwarding (proxying) the request to remote server?

Comment: Use a `break` suffix on the `rewrite` statement. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Thank you.  Adding a `break` helped.